# Most elegant way to find the position of the odd one out

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 3 strings, two of which are always equal. I want to find the odd one out. The problems sound super simple but I haven't been able to find a truly elegant way to do it.

For example, the list, `lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo']`, should return `1`. The way I am currently doing it is this:

```
f = lambda x, y, z: {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1}.get((x == y, x == z), 2)
ans = f(*lst)
```

Is there a *better* way here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could look for the first occurrence of the last value:

```
ans = (1, 0, 2)[lst.index(lst[2])]
```

Or if you're ok with index `-1` instead of `2`:

```
ans = 1 - lst.index(lst[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple method, though not very efficient:

```
odd_one_out = min(lst, key=lst.count)
```

To get the index:

```
odd_one_out_index = min(enumerate(lst), key=lambda i: lst.count(i[1]))[0]
```

This finds how often every element appears in the list, then selects the one with the lowest count. Note the `O(N^2)` efficiency though.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am actually after the index location of the odd one out.

Comment: I have updated my answer to get the index

Comment: @mousetail `lst.index(min(lst, key=lambda i: lst.count(i)))` wouldn't that line of code return the index position

Comment: Why do you wrap the perfectly fine function `lst.count` in an extra lambda?

Comment: @ProChess it will require one more pass on the list to find the item

Answer (score 2):

What about

```py
0 if lst[1] == lst[2] else 1 if lst[0] == lst[2] else 2
```